# Update user info using googleapi using php will make the predefine field empty if not updated

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm working to update the user info using googleapi in php.

When I run this code it will make the predefine field which I don't want to update empty.
As in this code I'm not setting Title as the title is already set but once I run this code the title will become empty.

How can I resolve it?

```
$organization = new \Google\Service\Directory\UserOrganization();
        $organization->setPrimary(TRUE);
      //  $organization->setTitle('Lead Developer');
        $organization->setDepartment('Dev');
        $googleUser->setOrganizations([$organization]);
        
        $gsdService->users->update('fname.lname@domain.com', $googleUser);
```

Comment: Why are you starting with a new instance of UserOrganization, instead of _fetching_ the current instance via the API first?

Comment: @CBroe how can I do it? I can't find anything how can I do it

Comment: Presumably the user object will not only have a method to _set_ the organizations, but also one to _get_ them ... If you are not sure what method exists, then you should check the documentation of the library you are using there.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm not setting the title but it's getting empty and not remaining the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the [user.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update?hl=en) method.  This method uses HTTP Put methodology and will update everything in the object exactly as you send it. So by not sending a title you are telling the system you want that field to be null.

If you only want to update the files that you send then you should be using [users.patch](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/patch?hl=en) which follows HTTP Patch methodology and only updates the properties that are sent in the user object.

```
$organization = new \Google\Service\Directory\UserOrganization();
$organization->setPrimary(TRUE);
$organization->setDepartment('Dev');
$googleUser->setOrganizations([$organization]);
    
$gsdService->users->patch('fname.lname@domain.com', $googleUser);
```

Comment: I tried patch and its working the same as update, The title field is still getting empty

Comment: It may be a bug then. I would do a get on it and grab the current title and then just reapply it in your update. You have to do that with some of the apis.

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation for [users.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) specifies:

> This method supports patch semantics, meaning you only need to include the fields you wish to update. Fields that are not present in the request will be preserved

The documentation for [orgunits.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/orgunits/update) just says:

> Updates an organizational unit.

So, you cannot expect `orgunits.update` to preserve not specified fields and it is not a bug.

You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to ask to support patch semantics for `orgunits.update`.

In the meantime, if you have problems with not empty fields being overwritten - consider as a workaround specifying in your `orgunits.update` request all fields that you do not want to become empty.